# Formula on conference t-shirt: $\ell(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i \sum_{k=0}^{K}x_{ik}\beta_{k}-\log\left(1+e^{\sum_{k=0}^{K}x_{ik}\beta_{k}}\right)$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I need some assistance figuring out what this formula signifies and what it does. It is from a shirt I got recently at a conference and am curious about it. Thanks!

> $$\ell(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i \sum_{k=0}^{K}x_{ik}\beta_{k}-\log\left(1+e^{\sum_{k=0}^{K}x_{ik}\beta_{k}}\right)$$

[image]

Comment: What was the conference about?

Comment: it was the UseR Conference at Stanford. The shirt was from the company 2Sigma. They are a hedge fund management company that uses Machine Learning for trading.

Comment: This appears to be a logarithm of a scaled form of logistic regression.

Comment: One way to figure out what it means (if no one here recognizes it) would presumably be to email someone from Two Sigma; presumably there's a relevant contact listed on their website.